# Shall I use my preferred font or dynamic font (system) in iOS development

Tags: ios, fonts, user-experience

I am new to iOS development. When I design the font used in my app's labels and textfields and textviews, I have two options and would like to hear your opinions regarding to good UX design practice:

1. I can choose my preferred font and font size.
2. I can stick to system type (which I think can change according to user settings). Then I only need to choose whether I want System type for text body, header, title 1, title 2, etc.

Please assume that the app is mainly a text reading app in which allowing users to clearly read a (not-so-long) paragraph of English is critical.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. Some prefer custom fonts (like Microsoft apps) to differentiate themselves, while others prefer system fonts. In either case, you can use custom fonts with dynamic type, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20510095/983912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System fonts are best suited for your needs. They can be changed with accessibility parameters, if user wishes to. Your custom ones can't. Moreover, it will have consistent look with the iOS, since you will be using default fonts. You still can configure it, using thin, light, bold weights etc.
I personally stick with system ones if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apple prefers for you to use the System fonts, so that the user can choose their own settings for it. If your app is mostly text reading, then I would stick with the System fonts.

Comment: Chris, your answer is good, too. However, I chose to select Soberman's just because of the extra bit of information. Thank you.