# Dynamic Font Required in iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

In the iOS Program requirements it says that

> "3.3.7 Applications must comply with the Human Interface Guidelines and other
>   Documentation provided by Apple."

When I read the Human Interface Guideline one part of it says:

> "Ensure legibility by using the system font. San Francisco (the iOS system font) works with Dynamic Type to automatically adjust letter spacing and line height so that text is easy to read and looks great at every size. Whether you use San Francisco or a custom font, be sure to adopt Dynamic Type so your app can respond when the user chooses a different text size."

Does that mean I have to support dynamic type in my iOS app?

Comment: I would say it's not required but you should really think twice when breaking design guidelines.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement the dynamic font in custom font then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Type isn't *required*, no. Compliance with the HIG is a pretty loose requirement itself, considering the HIG is only a guideline.

Despite not being required, seriously consider incorporating it into your app. It's a great feature for accessibility and user-control. There are some [great writeups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510094/how-to-use-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-text-sizes-in-ios7) on using Dynamic Type with fonts other than San Francisco, if that's a concern.

Comment: Ok, awesome! I will checkout that article and probably try to add Dynamic Type to my font. I just wanted to use fonts other than San Fransisco, and that would be great since I can incorporate Dynamic Type with other fonts. Thanks so much!