# A better way to use Dynamic Type with a custom font in Swift 3/iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uifontdescriptor, dynamic-type-feature

I tried two ways:

### Method 1:

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

This works fine, even when the preferred text size is changed in the Settings, the text size changes automatically, even before when I go back to the app. **But** it only works with the system font (San Francisco).

### Method 2:

To use a custom font, I add an extension to `UIFontDescriptor`:

```
//from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35467158/2907715
extension UIFontDescriptor {

    private struct SubStruct {
        static var preferredFontName: String = "Avenir-medium"
    }

    static let fontSizeTable : NSDictionary = [
        UIFontTextStyle.headline: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 16,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 15,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 14
        ],
        UIFontTextStyle.subheadline: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 15,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 14,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 13,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 12
        ],
        UIFontTextStyle.body: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 53,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 47,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 40,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 33,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 28,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 21,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 16,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 15,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 14
        ],
        UIFontTextStyle.caption1: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 16,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 14,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 12,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 11,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 11,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 11
        ],
        UIFontTextStyle.caption2: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 15,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 13,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 11,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 11,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 11,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 11
        ],
        UIFontTextStyle.footnote: [
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityExtraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.accessibilityMedium: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraExtraLarge: 17,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraLarge: 15,
            UIContentSizeCategory.large: 13,
            UIContentSizeCategory.medium: 12,
            UIContentSizeCategory.small: 12,
            UIContentSizeCategory.extraSmall: 12
        ],
        ]

    final class func preferredDescriptor(textStyle: String) -> UIFontDescriptor {

        let contentSize = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory
        let style = fontSizeTable[textStyle] as! NSDictionary
        return UIFontDescriptor(name: SubStruct.preferredFontName, size: CGFloat((style[contentSize] as! NSNumber).floatValue))
    }

}
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
label.font = UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor.preferredDescriptor(textStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body.rawValue), size: 0)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.userChangedTextSize(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object: nil)
```

here is the `userChangedTextSize` function:

```
func userChangedTextSize(notification: NSNotification) {
    label.font = UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor.preferredDescriptor(textStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body.rawValue), size: 0)
}
```

**The problem** with this method is that the text size won't change until the user goes back to the app, and then the user would see the old text size change to the new size, which is not ideal.

Could I have the best of both worlds: a custom font with a size that changes automatically in the background?

Comment: on iOS 11 you can use UIFontMetrics

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> The problem with this method is that the text size won't change until the user goes back to the app, and then the user would see the old text size change to the new size, which is not ideal.

I share your thoughts that this would probably be a better UX, but I guess you are overthinking it a bit.

If you have a look at system provided Apps (e.g. Contacts) you will clearly see that the **refresh is not done until the user goes back to the app**, too.

By the way, you could refactor your code a bit for Swift 3:

```
extension UIFontDescriptor {

    private struct SubStruct {
        static var preferredFontName: String = "Avenir-medium"
    }

    static let fontSizeTable: [UIFontTextStyle: [UIContentSizeCategory: CGFloat]] = [
        .headline: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 23,
            .accessibilityLarge: 23,
            .accessibilityMedium: 23,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            .extraExtraLarge: 21,
            .extraLarge: 19,
            .large: 17,
            .medium: 16,
            .small: 15,
            .extraSmall: 14
        ],
        .subheadline: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 21,
            .accessibilityLarge: 21,
            .accessibilityMedium: 21,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
            .extraExtraLarge: 19,
            .extraLarge: 17,
            .large: 15,
            .medium: 14,
            .small: 13,
            .extraSmall: 12
        ],
        .body: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 53,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 47,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 40,
            .accessibilityLarge: 33,
            .accessibilityMedium: 28,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
            .extraExtraLarge: 21,
            .extraLarge: 19,
            .large: 17,
            .medium: 16,
            .small: 15,
            .extraSmall: 14
        ],
        .caption1: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 18,
            .accessibilityLarge: 18,
            .accessibilityMedium: 18,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
            .extraExtraLarge: 16,
            .extraLarge: 14,
            .large: 12,
            .medium: 11,
            .small: 11,
            .extraSmall: 11
        ],
        .caption2: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 17,
            .accessibilityLarge: 17,
            .accessibilityMedium: 17,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
            .extraExtraLarge: 15,
            .extraLarge: 13,
            .large: 11,
            .medium: 11,
            .small: 11,
            .extraSmall: 11
        ],
        .footnote: [
            .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            .accessibilityExtraLarge: 19,
            .accessibilityLarge: 19,
            .accessibilityMedium: 19,
            .extraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
            .extraExtraLarge: 17,
            .extraLarge: 15,
            .large: 13,
            .medium: 12,
            .small: 12,
            .extraSmall: 12
        ]
    ]

    final class func preferredDescriptor(textStyle: UIFontTextStyle) -> UIFontDescriptor {
        let contentSize = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory
        let style = fontSizeTable[textStyle]!
        return UIFontDescriptor(name: SubStruct.preferredFontName, size: style[contentSize]!)
    }
}
```

No need to cast to `NSDictionary` or `NSNumber` and get the `floatValue` indirectly.

This way your call site can use the following, more readable code:

```
func userChangedTextSize(notification: NSNotification) {
    label.font = UIFont(descriptor: .preferredDescriptor(textStyle: .body), size: 0)

}
```

**Edit: As I am working on the same right now, I improved the above (on SO commonly seen solution) to something way easier.**

```
import UIKIt

extension UIFont {

    private struct CustomFont {
        static var fontFamily = "Avenir"
    }

    /// Returns a bold version of `self`
    public var bolded: UIFont {
        return fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)
            .map { UIFont(descriptor: $0, size: 0) } ?? self
    }

    /// Returns an italic version of `self`
    public var italicized: UIFont {
        return fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)
            .map { UIFont(descriptor: $0, size: 0) } ?? self
    }

    /// Returns a scaled version of `self`
    func scaled(scaleFactor: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        let newDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSize(fontDescriptor.pointSize * scaleFactor)
        return UIFont(descriptor: newDescriptor, size: 0)
    }

    class func preferredCustomFont(forTextStyle textStyle: UIFontTextStyle) -> UIFont {
        // we are using the UIFontDescriptor which is less expensive than creating an intermediate UIFont
        let systemFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: textStyle)

        let customFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.init(fontAttributes: [
            UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute: CustomFont.fontFamily,
            UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute: systemFontDescriptor.pointSize // use the font size of the default dynamic font
        ])

        // return font of new family with same size as the preferred system font
        return UIFont(descriptor: customFontDescriptor, size: 0)
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
func userChangedTextSize(notification: NSNotification) {
    label.font = UIFont.preferredCustomFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
    // or in Bold / Italic:
    // label.font = UIFont.preferredCustomFont(forTextStyle: .headline).bolded
    // label.font = UIFont.preferredCustomFont(forTextStyle: .headline).italicized
}
```

Comment: This is definitely more romantic. The first version gives more control over the size to give text when the UIContentSizeCategory changes: you don't have to use the default sizes (11...53), Which could mess up the whole ui hierarchy and nothing would be readable on iPhone plus sizes. The Medium app reacts to UIContentSizeCategory changes in a subtle way: changing the font size by a smidgen and increasing the line height.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to combine the solutions to have the best of both approaches. Agreed, the previous gives you subtle control over the sizes to provide good and readable layouts while still decreasing/increasing the type. As far as I can see the given code uses the defaults, so my approach would be a viable shortening for anyone who wants to stick to the defaults. Medium is a very good example for using custom sizes! I still wonder why `.Body` is increased up to 53 points by Apple.. This would break nearly every thinkable layout.

Comment: [Bonmot](https://github.com/Raizlabs/BonMot) can monitor content size category changes. But still the result isn't smooth enough. Even using `viewWillAppear` isn't enough because the app switcher keeps a snapshot of the app using the previous content size. Anyway, later on I'll look into animating the content size category change: e.g going from `large` to `accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge` would go through all `UIContentSizeCategory`s in between, inspired by [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/live-font-interpolation-on-the-web)

Comment: I really like this approach - it also makes it very easy to have more than one custom font.

Comment: Note that for iOS 10 and higher, you don't have to respond to the `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange` notification anymore, but can set `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` for the label. Also supposed to work for `UITextField` and `UITextView`.

Comment: when ' userChangedTextSize '  is getting called? i put breakpoint there and it never get called for me.

Comment: @BenShabat You likely missed adding the NotificationCenter `addObserver` in `viewDidLoad` (see the initial question for details). Could you please check that?

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf i figured out how to work it out i had to use traitCollectionDidChange

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that you figured it out! My post likely needs a bit of an overhaul for alle the changes since early 2017..

Comment: I tried this solution it doesn't notice my custom font , it use the default font , I'm very sure I change 'fontFamily' to my custom font

Comment: @Basil for Custom Fonts in iOS you'll always have to add them to the Info.plist first, you're likely missing them there. Thus said, this solution is a couple of years old now and I would tend to use other approaches available with newer iOS Versions now (using `scaledFont`). See this blog for more insights: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-type/.

Answer (score 3):

*Frederik's Winkelsdorf* version fo code but tweaked to use two different Font Family (default one and bold) plus sample of usage.

**MyFontExtension.swift**

```
import UIKit
extension UIFontDescriptor {
    private struct FontFamily {
        static var preferredFontNameRegular: String = "Montserrat-Regular"
        static var preferredFontNameBold: String = "Montserrat-Bold"
    }
    
    static let fontSizeTable: [UIFontTextStyle: [UIContentSizeCategory: CGFloat]] = [
    .headline: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 23,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 23,
        .accessibilityLarge: 23,
        .accessibilityMedium: 23,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
        .extraExtraLarge: 21,
        .extraLarge: 19,
        .large: 17,
        .medium: 16,
        .small: 15,
        .extraSmall: 14
    ],
    .subheadline: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 21,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 21,
        .accessibilityLarge: 21,
        .accessibilityMedium: 21,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 21,
        .extraExtraLarge: 19,
        .extraLarge: 17,
        .large: 15,
        .medium: 14,
        .small: 13,
        .extraSmall: 12
    ],
    .body: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 53,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 47,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 40,
        .accessibilityLarge: 33,
        .accessibilityMedium: 28,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 23,
        .extraExtraLarge: 21,
        .extraLarge: 19,
        .large: 17,
        .medium: 16,
        .small: 15,
        .extraSmall: 14
    ],
    .caption1: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 18,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 18,
        .accessibilityLarge: 18,
        .accessibilityMedium: 18,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 18,
        .extraExtraLarge: 16,
        .extraLarge: 14,
        .large: 12,
        .medium: 11,
        .small: 11,
        .extraSmall: 11
    ],
    .caption2: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 17,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 17,
        .accessibilityLarge: 17,
        .accessibilityMedium: 17,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 17,
        .extraExtraLarge: 15,
        .extraLarge: 13,
        .large: 11,
        .medium: 11,
        .small: 11,
        .extraSmall: 11
    ],
    .footnote: [
        .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
        .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge: 19,
        .accessibilityExtraLarge: 19,
        .accessibilityLarge: 19,
        .accessibilityMedium: 19,
        .extraExtraExtraLarge: 19,
        .extraExtraLarge: 17,
        .extraLarge: 15,
        .large: 13,
        .medium: 12,
        .small: 12,
        .extraSmall: 12
    ]
]
    
    final class func preferredDescriptor(textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle, styleBold: Bool = false) -> UIFontDescriptor {
        let contentSize = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory
                
        let fontFamily = styleBold ? FontFamily.preferredFontNameBold : FontFamily.preferredFontNameRegular
        
        guard let style = fontSizeTable[textStyle], let size = style[contentSize] else {
            return UIFontDescriptor(name: fontFamily, size: 16)
        }
        return UIFontDescriptor(name: fontFamily, size: size)
    }
}
```

**myViewController.swift**

```
myBoldLabel.font = UIFont(descriptor: .preferredDescriptor(textStyle: .body, styleBold: true), size: 0)

myNormalLabel.font = UIFont(descriptor: .preferredDescriptor(textStyle: .body), size: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:** Custom scaled Font supporting Accessibility (German BITV)

```
//UIFont+CustomScaledFont.swift

import UIKit

extension UIFont {

    /// Scaled and styled version of any custom Font
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - name: Name of the Font
    ///   - textStyle: The text style i.e Body, Title, ...
    /// - Returns: The scaled custom Font version with the given textStyle 
    static func scaledFont(name:String, textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle) -> UIFont {

        let fontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: textStyle)

        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: name, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load the \(name) font.")
        }

        return UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont)
    }
}
```

After successfully adding custom fonts to your project...

**Print available font names:**

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames {
    for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
        print(name)
    }
 }
```

**Setup Example:**

```
myLabel.text = "My scaled custom Font"
myLabel.font = UIFont.scaledFont(name: "MyCustomFontName-Bold", textStyle: .title1)
myLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

Test with Accessibility Inspector (MacOS)

Comment: This does not work if the app launch with non-default scale. `UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: textStyle)` will get the scaled value, and use `scaledFont` method it will scaled again.

Comment: Thank you, this solution working great with me

Comment: UIFontMetrics is for iOS11 and above, the question asked about iOS10.

Answer (score 1):

Fred answer but in Swift 5 (I tried to edit the original post but the edit queue is always full):

```swift
import UIKit

extension UIFont {

    private struct CustomFont {
        static var fontFamily = "Avenir"
    }

    /// Returns a bold version of `self`
    public var bolded: UIFont {
        return fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)
            .map { UIFont(descriptor: $0, size: 0) } ?? self
    }

    /// Returns an italic version of `self`
    public var italicized: UIFont {
        return fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)
            .map { UIFont(descriptor: $0, size: 0) } ?? self
    }

    /// Returns a scaled version of `self`
    func scaled(scaleFactor: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        let newDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSize(fontDescriptor.pointSize * scaleFactor)
        return UIFont(descriptor: newDescriptor, size: 0)
    }

    class func preferredCustomFont(forTextStyle textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle) -> UIFont {
        // we are using the UIFontDescriptor which is less expensive than creating an intermediate UIFont
        let systemFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: textStyle)

        let customFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.init(fontAttributes: [
            UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.family: CustomFont.fontFamily,
            UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.size: systemFontDescriptor.pointSize // use the font size of the default dynamic font
        ])

        // return font of new family with same size as the preferred system font
        return UIFont(descriptor: customFontDescriptor, size: 0)
    }

}
```