# Change all UILabels for a specific UIFont.TextStyle

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm using `TextStyles` in my app to support dynamic fonts. I have the challenge to change the Font for each `TextStyle`. So for example the `TextStyle.body` should be *MyAwesomeBODYFont* and the `TextStyle.headline` should be *MyAwesomeHeadlineFont*. And this for the entire app. Setting the font for the whole app won't work because I need several Fonts for the different styles.

**Is it possible to override these `TextStyles` somehow with custom fonts for the entire app and not for each label separately?**

What I tried:

Setting the font for the `appearance` proxy of `UILabel` in general works fine:

```
let labelAppearance = UILabel.appearance()
let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
labelAppearance.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: myAwesomeBodyFont)
```

But this overrides all labels not matter what `TextStyle` they use.

After that I tried to check for the `TextStyle` but it crashes with a nil pointer exception for the UILabel.appearance().font or does not even go into the if-block.

```
let labelAppearance = UILabel.appearance()
if let textStyle = labelAppearance.font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.textStyle) as? UIFont.TextStyle {
    // this would be the place to check for the TextStyle and use the corresponding font

    let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: textStyle)
    labelAppearance.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: mayAwesomeBodyFont)
}
```

Because the appearance of UILabel does not have a `font` set.

Comment: You cannot directly "set" a custom font for Text Styles. I'd suggest searching for `dynamic type custom font` - you'll find many resources.  Here is one place to start: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-type/

Comment: Thanks for the search recommendation! I actually searched for the exact term already and used this article :) I specified my question a bit.

Comment: TypographyKit is a third party module that can help with this problem.

Comment: TypographyKit sounded interesting when I found it but it also sets this for every single label resp. UI component. Thanks for your comment anyway, I looked into the Framework again but could not find their solution for that specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a subclass of UILabel and let all my labels inherit from it. This way you can set the class in InterfaceBuilder and/or create the custom class in code.

This is the DynamicCustomFontLabel class:

```
import UIKit

class DynamicCustomFontLabel: UILabel {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        initCustomFont()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        initCustomFont()
    }

    private func initCustomFont() {
        if let textStyle = font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.textStyle) as? UIFont.TextStyle {
            let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: textStyle)
            var customFont: UIFont?

            switch textStyle {
            case .body:
                customFont = UIFont(name: "MyAwesomeBODYFont", size: 21)

            case .headline:
                customFont = UIFont(name: "MyAwesomeHeadlineFont", size: 48)

            // all other cases...

            default:
                return
            }

            guard let font = customFont else {
                fatalError("Failed to load a custom font! Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font is added to the Info.plist.")
            }

            self.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide example of using this class?

Comment: @marika.daboja you can use it as any other UILabel you would use, since the class inherits from that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly "set" a custom font for Text Styles.
You can get font size for text style and then could use custom family.

```
let systemDynamicFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
let size = systemDynamicFontDescriptor.pointSize
let font = UIFont(name: MyAwesomeBODYFont, size: size)
```

For iOS 11+ There is `scaledFont()`

You can make this font variable static and could use it everywhere in app.

You could check it out this solution too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235227/4846167

Comment: Thanks @Aaiana for your answer. Maybe I wasn't very specific in my question. I edit my post. I'm looking for a general solution where I don't need to set this for each label.

Comment: Got your point. Maybe check it out this http://curtclifton.net/fonts-with-style. Article is old but can give some idea.