# iOS: font sizes in a React Native view do not match iOS native font sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts, react-native

I have two views: a React Native view and an iOS native view. They both contain labels. Labels has font size 14. But on iPhone 6 font sizes are different: the iOS native view has bigger letters than a React Native view. I need to make the fonts the same. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. The reason of the issue was the following: a text size was changed on the iPhone in Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Text Size. React Native supports Dynamic Type, but the application hardcoded the text size in the native code. To fix the issue it is needed to support Dynamic Type on the native app side. See details about how to support it here: [How to use a custom font with dynamic text sizes in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510094/how-to-use-a-custom-font-with-dynamic-text-sizes-in-ios7)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

try this:

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>
      Hi! I will not change. I don't respect settings.
</Text>
```

I found it here: https://joshbuchea.com/react-native-text-size-font-scaling.